# How beam.io.ReadFromPubSub output Pcollection is defined in Apache Beam/Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

Let's say we have simple streaming pipeline in which we read data from PubSub.
I am wondering how the output of this step is defined.
If we stream 10 messages, one after another, all of those 10 messages will be a member of single Pcollection or maybe those will be 10 Pcollections with single element each?

Answer (score 1):

They will be emitted down the pipeline as 10 individual PCollections, containing the PubSub message as content. See the [source code](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.html#PubsubMessage) of `ReadFromPubSub`.

Furthermore, depending on the flag `with_attributes` and the message published on PubSub, the content of the PCollection does not necessarily be one single element.